# Javascript looping nested click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a nested click event listeners and I have a problem, that when I trigger the event listeners multiple times they get looped and send a request x2 times than it should. Where is the mistake in my code? It's probably a beginner's mistake, so I'm very sorry if that's the case. I'm still learning JavaScript and jQuery.

Code:

```
    $('body').on('click', '.color-pick-btn', function() {
      id = $(this).data("highlight");
      unique = $(this).data("unique");

      $(".color-picker").show();
      //show the menu directly over the placeholder
      $(".color-picker").position({
        my: "right top",
        at: "right bottom",
        of: this,
        collision: "fit"
      });

      $('body').on('click', '.color-picker-item', function() {
        color = $(this).data("color");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
          url: '/echo/json',
          //data: "highlight=" + id + '&color=' + color + "&unique=" + unique,
          data: {
          json:'{"highlight":"id","color":"color","unique": "unique"}'
          },
          dataType: 'json',
        }).done(function(data) {
          console.log('test');
        });
        $(".color-picker").hide();
        return false;
      });

      $(document).click(function(event) {
        if (!(($(event.target).hasClass('color-pick-btn')) || ($(event.target).hasClass('color-picker-item')))) {
          $(".color-picker").hide();
        }
        return false;
      });
      return false;
    });
```

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/o0r4z6g3/

Check out the console output "test".

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added event listeners every time your event listener was called. I haven't taken a look at the intention of your code, and you haven't explained it in your answer, but this may fix your problem.

```
$('body').on('click', '.color-pick-btn', function() {
  // .position() uses position relative to the offset parent, 
  // so it supports position: relative parent elements
  pos = $(this).offset();
  id = $(this).data("highlight");
  unique = $(this).data("unique");

  // .outerWidth() takes into account border and padding.
  width = $(this).outerWidth();
  $(".color-picker").show();
  //show the menu directly over the placeholder
  $(".color-picker").position({
    my: "right top",
    at: "right bottom",
    of: this,
    collision: "fit"
  });

  return false;
});

$('body').on('click', '.color-picker-item', function() {
  color = $(this).data("color");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/echo/json',
    //data: "highlight=" + id + '&color=' + color + "&unique=" + unique,
    data: {
      json: '{"highlight":"id","color":"color","unique": "unique"}'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log('test');
  });
  $(".color-picker").hide();
  return false;
});

$(document).click(function(event) {
  if (!(($(event.target).hasClass('color-pick-btn')) || ($(event.target).hasClass('color-picker-item')))) {
    $(".color-picker").hide();
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. Can I ask how is it possible that the first click event can pass the variable "id" and "unique" to the second event listener when they are two different functions

Comment: @popcorn you could use a global variable (not the ideal solution), but without more information about what this code is doing and what unique and highlight represent, it is very difficult to give you a better answer.

Comment: Although, you could just do `const  id = $('.color-pick-btn').data("highlight");` in the second event listener.

Comment: That's what I want - to pass the variables from first function to the second, that's why I thought it has to be nested. However, the `const id = $('.color-pick-btn').data("highlight");` won't work with multiple buttons. The answer above it enough for me, thanks